# How to add numpy arrays as values in a dictionary of dictionaries?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, word2vec

Assume I have the following variables:

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
wv = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', binary=True)
dict_dict = {
    "abc": ('dog', 'cat', 'bat'),
    "def": ('fat', 'hat', 'rat')
}
```

In this situation, `wv` is a word2vec model.

I want to take the values of each key in `dict_dict`, extract the value's vector (`e.g. wv['dog']`), and have the value now acts as a key to a sub dictionary:

```
dict_dict = {
    "abc": ({'dog': array([ 5.12695312e-02, -2.23388672e-02, -1.72851562e-01,  1.61132812e-01]), {'cat':array([ 5.12695312e-02, -2.23388672e-02, -1.72851562e-01,  1.61132812e-01]), array([ 5.12695312e-02, -2.23388672e-02, -1.72851562e-01,  1.61132812e-01]):'bat')}
```

Would I have to create a new dictionary to do this?

Comment: What's the problem?  Sounds like a normal iteration over dictionary keys.  An array as value is no different from any other kind of object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace each of the existing `dict_dict` values – which are currently tuples – with new dicts, created via a Python dict comprehension. For example:

```py
for key in dict_dict.keys():
    words = dict_dict[key]
    subdict = { word : wv[word] for word in words}
    dict_dict[key] = subdict
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I couldn't figure out how to formalize this, so this helps a lot!

Comment: You're welcome! It's also possible as a 1-liner with *nested* comprehensions, without an explicit `for` loop & local vars, but the above is clearer. (The 1-liner would be: `dict_dict = { k : { word : wv[word] for word in dict_dict[k]} for k, v in dict_dict.items() }`.)